# When QDockWidget with QWebEngineView is undocked, other docked widgets don't respond to user action

Tags: c++, qt

I have multiple dockwidgets in my main window and everything works fine until I add a dockedwidget with QwebEngineView as the widget.

When a dockwidget with QwebEngineView as a child is undocked, user inputs such as scroll bars in the other docked widgets are ignored. When the dockwidget with QWebEngineView is docked, it works fine.

The code I am testing with is the example project in 
   ..\Qt 5.6\widgets\mainwindows\dockwidgets
with minor modification to add one more dockedwidget with QWebEngineView (see below).

```
///// added this in void MainWindow::createDockWindows()

WebView* w_view = new WebView(nullptr);
dock = new QDockWidget(tr("WebView"), this);
dock->setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
dock->setWidget(w_view);
addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dock);
viewMenu->addAction(dock->toggleViewAction());


///  the widget with QWebEngineView
class WebView : public QWidget {
     Q_OBJECT
 public:
 WebView(QWidget* parent = 0)
    :QWidget(parent)
{
    setObjectName("WebView");
    m_webEngineView = new QWebEngineView(this);
    m_webEngineView->load(QUrl("http://qt-project.org/"));
}

    ~WebView() {}
private:
    QWebEngineView* m_webEngineView;
};
///////////////////////////
```

Any help?

Comment: I've tried it and it works correctly.

Comment: @eyllanesc which version and platform did you try it on?

Comment: Linux, Qt 5.10.

Comment: OK, thanks. I am using windows 10. I have tried it with 5.9 but not with 5.10. I will try that next.

Comment: QtWebEngine has had several bugs in windows, I recommend checking if your problem is one of them, so in your case I would report it to Qt.

Comment: yeah, I will do that after testing with 5.10. It seems the issue appeared after QDockWidget improvements in 5.6. it works for other widgets though so it seems to be an issue when using QWebEngineview.